# Django Tastypie - Prepend URLs does not work

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I tried to use the `prepend_url()` function similar to the search example in the [tastypie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html). For some reason the browser returned just a 404 and nothing else happens...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cookbook refers to the 0.9.12 version which is just an alpha version. The `prepend_urls()` function is not implemented in the older versions. Therefore the function is simply not called and does not trigger an error message.

So you have to install the alpha or use the `override_urls()` function ([documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=override#override-urls))